# Sort dates inside a method of a linked list

Tags: java, sorting, date, linked-list

I have a bunch of dates added to a todo list `list2016` and now I need these todo list items to be ordered by date (soonest first, latest last).

It should all happen inside my `add` method but I have no clue how to do so. Any ideas?

```
public class ToDoListEntry 
{
    String task;
    LocalDate date;
    ToDoListEntry next;

    public ToDoListEntry(LocalDate date, String task) 
    {
        this.task = task;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Then comes the next where I tried to add an array but which did not work:

```
public class ToDoList 
{
    ToDoListEntry first;
    int size;

    public ToDoList ()
    {
        first = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(ToDoListEntry newTask) 
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = newTask;
        }
        else
        {
            ToDoListEntry zeiger = first;
            while (zeiger.next != null)
            {
                zeiger = zeiger.next;
            }
            zeiger.next = newTask;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public String print()
    {
        String result = "";
        if (first == null) 
        {
            result = "Empty list!\n";
        } 
        else 
        {
            ToDoListEntry pointer = first;
            while (pointer != null) 
            {
                result += "Until " + pointer.date + " Task: " + pointer.task + "\n";
                pointer = pointer.next;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And in the end, the main class. It is supposed to create a new `ToDoList` and print it out (Note that I did not include the `print()` method):

```
public class MyMainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Test 00: Empty List");
        ToDoList list2016 = new ToDoList();

        list2016.print(); 

        System.out.println("Test 01: add");
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 8, 15), "Do workout"));
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 6, 3), "Buy apples"));
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 10, 11), "Read Books"));
        list2016.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand? Let's say you have sorted invoices, and you find an old one that must be inserted at the right location in the pile of invoices. What's your strategy?

Comment: Why don't you use build-in collection like an ArrayList/LinkedList (instead creating own implementation of LinkedList) and sort it using your custom Comparator?

Comment: Is there a reason you must create your own linked list structure as opposed to using Java collection classes? I.e. is this a homework?

Comment: @paisanco yes, it is a homework so I have to use LinkedLists

Comment: It makes the question tough to answer without knowing your instructors intent, do they want you to find the most efficient algorithm or is a brute force approach enough as long as it works?

Comment: @paisanco No we don't have to find the best algorithm. Everything is okay as long as it works.

Comment: @Yanlu is my answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an inefficient and messy way of doing it. However to achieve what you want I changed two of your classes. These classes were your `ToDoList` class and your `main` class.

**ToDoList.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class ToDoList 
{
    ToDoListEntry first;
    ArrayList<LocalDate> datesList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList();

    public ToDoList ()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    public void add(ToDoListEntry newTask)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = newTask;
        }
        else
        {
            ToDoListEntry zeiger = first;
            while (zeiger.next != null)
            {
                zeiger = zeiger.next;
            }
            zeiger.next = newTask;
        }
    }

    public void sortDates()
    {
        Collections.sort(datesList);
    }

    public void compareAndSort()
    {
        ArrayList<String> tempDates = new ArrayList();
        for(LocalDate lD:datesList)
        {
            tempDates.add(lD+"");
        }
        ArrayList<String> tempSorted = new ArrayList();
        for(String s:tempDates)
        {
            for(String a:results)
            {
                if(a.contains(s))
                {
                    if(!tempSorted.contains(a))
                    {
                        tempSorted.add(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        results=tempSorted;
        for(String s:results)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public String print()
    {
        String result = "";
        if (first == null) 
        {
            result = "Empty list!\n";
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        else 
        {
            ToDoListEntry pointer = first;
            while (pointer != null) 
            {
                result += "Until " + pointer.date + " Task: "+ pointer.task +"\n";
                if(LocalDate.now().isBefore(pointer.date))
                {
                    results.add("Until " + pointer.date + " Task: "+ pointer.task);
                }

                datesList.add(pointer.date);
                pointer = pointer.next;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String printDates()
    {
        String dates = datesList.toString();
        System.out.println(dates);
        return dates;
    }
}
```

**Test.java** (This is what you described as your `main` class)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Test 00: Empty List");
        ToDoList list2016 = new ToDoList();

        list2016.print(); 

        System.out.println("Test 01: add");
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 8, 15), "Do workout"));
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 18), "Hand in Homework"));
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 6, 3), "Buy apples"));
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 10, 11), "Read Books"));
        list2016.add(new ToDoListEntry(LocalDate.of(2016, 10, 11), "Read Homework"));

        list2016.print();
        list2016.sortDates();
        list2016.compareAndSort();
    }
}
```

I have two notes.

The first is since you specifically said `soonest` I have added a function which removes dates that have already passed the current dates. You could change this later if you like by changing the if statement `if(LocalDate.now().isBefore(pointer.date))`

Secondly your `ToDoList.print()` doesn't actually print anything any-more unless `first` is null.